# How to print and show the error message of twitter api to user

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

```js
const Twitter = require('twitter');

    
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXXX'
});

client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Hii twitter test 123'}, function(
  error,
  tweet,
  response
) {
  if (error) throw error;
  //console.log(tweet); // Tweet body.
  console.log(response); // Raw response object.
//  response.on('end', function() {console.log(data)});
});
```

I want to show this error message to user how I can show this. Here, I am trying to tweet the duplicate tweet and twitter api response message: 'Status is a duplicate.' So I jus want to show the user whatever the error message will come from twitter api response.

C:\Users\shdfhd\sdfksdjf\Nodeapplication2.js:22
if (error) throw error;
^
[ { code: 187, message: 'Status is a duplicate.' } ]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by "show the user" but I guess you are talking about printing to console judging from the code.
You can just use long notation for the if block and log the error message before the error is thrown.

```js
const Twitter = require('twitter');

    
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'XXXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token_key: 'XXXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXXX'
});

client.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Hii twitter test 123'}, function(
  error,
  tweet,
  response
) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
  //console.log(tweet); // Tweet body.
  console.log(response); // Raw response object.
//  response.on('end', function() {console.log(data)});
});
```